# Refresh Power Pivot Window

Tags: excel, pivot, powerpivot, vba

How to automatically Refresh Power Pivot Window when i open excel file , without going the `Power Pivot Window` option in power pivot tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vinoth,

It is possible to write VBA that triggers a 'refresh all' by placing the code in the Workbook module and using the Open_Event to trigger it as the workbook is opened.

If you are using 2010 then you will need to use this highly innovative technique developed by a guy called [Tom Gleeson](http://blog.gobansaor.com/vba-code-to-automate-a-powerpivot-refresh/).

If you are using 2013 then things become more straightforward as the data model is formally exposed to VBA. There are several resources out there including [this](http://www.vandeputte.org/2012/07/powerpivot-nuggets-part-18-automate.html).

HTH
Jacob

Comment: i'm totally confused!.I'm new to VBA....Actually, in Power Pivot Window , i'm getting the Data from 'SQL Server'(i.e Power Pivot Window -> Home->From Database option). If any changes made in Data Base it automatically reflect the Power Pivot Window, when i open Excel. For Example : For Refreshing the Excel Page, we using "ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll".like this any option available for power pivot window to refresh it?...

Comment: Vinoth, which version are you using 2010 or 2013? Either way the information in the links I posted should be of use.

Comment: Thanks for your info.
I'm using both version...
But i can't able to get in 2010 version, can't able to refresh the powerpivot window, Only refreshing the excel file.

Comment: Have you tried the code from Tom's site in your 2010 version? What error message do you get?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Refresh All button in the PowerPivot tab that you can use for this purpose. This avoids having to open the PowerPivot window just for refresh.

A caveat though: From what I remember, this just updates the tables which are linked from your current Excel workbook - for other types of connection, you have to go to PowerPivot window and refresh the respective tables.

Here is some information I found on a solution for your issue in Excel 2013:
http://www.vandeputte.org/2012/07/powerpivot-nuggets-part-18-automate.html

Answer (score 0):

From Excel (not Power Pivot Manager), open:

- Data
- Connections
- Connections

Then, select your data source and click *Properties*. You should see a checkbox for refreshing the data when the file is opened.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. I'm using Excel 2013 and it doesn't work the way you say.

Comment: @kgdesouz So the options are there, it's just not refreshing on open?

Answer (score 0):

You can also **right click** on any Power Pivot chart or tables and **click PivotTable Option...** and than under **data** you can select **Refresh data when opening the file**

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2013 allows for complete data model refresh through VBA. I added a button on my dashboard and assigned the following macro:

Sub Refresh()

ActiveWorkbook.Model.Refresh

End Sub

-Melissa

Answer (score 0):

This is an Excel 2010 specific issue. In Excel 2013 and later the Refresh icon on the Excel ribbon does what you'd expect it to. In Excel 2010 however linked tables, the data model and pivot tables/charts aren't refreshed by the Refresh icon.

We have a solution much better and simpler than the one Tom Gleeson describes https://ukanexcel.wordpress.com/2016/11/30/refreshing-power-pivot-in-excel-2010/

Comment: perhaps you could put some of your solution in your answer rather than just linking to it.